# Need Sample code to integrate phoneGap app with PWA. Is PhoneGap good to integrate apps or not?

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap, progressive-web-apps

How can I integrate the PhoneGap app with PWA, I have searched but didn't find any sample code? And can anybody tell me why PhoneGap is not so popular? Is it good to use or not? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a native app, which means you need a platform specific API not available yet in the browser, like Cortana or Siri as an example. Then I highly recommend https://pwabuilder.com because it will create native app packages for iOS, Android and Windows for you.

Comment: Thanks, Chris for your reply. I will check and let you know if I face any issue.